# How to access a camera-device on the new version of Android OS programmatically?

Tags: android, android-camera2

Because the library 'android.hardware.Camera' has been deprecated on the current version of Android OS, the older usage has been disabled.
And I don't know how to programmatically access the instance of the camera on the current version of Android.

The current library is 'android.hardware.camera2.*'.

Does anyone know how to do this ?
Thanks.

Comment: See this link https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample from Google: **https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java**

I also made a library to use simply Camera2, you may want to give it a shot!

**https://github.com/omaflak/Android-Camera2-Library**

This is how it looks like at the end:

```
EZCam cam = new EZCam(this);
cam.selectCamera(EZCam.FRONT); // or EZCam.BACK
cam.setStopPreviewOnPicture(true);

cam.setEZCamCallback(new EZCam.EZCamCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPicture(ImageReader reader) {
        // picture available
        cam.saveImage(reader, "image.jpeg"); // save to internal storage
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String message) {
        // error occurred
    }
});

TextureView textureView = (TextureView)findViewById(R.id.textureView);
textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {
        cam.startPreview(surfaceTexture, i, i1);
    }
});

// take picture
cam.takePicture();

// stop preview
cam.stopPreview();

// resume preview
cam.resumePreview();
```

To install the library, add in your gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'me.aflak.libraries:ezcam:1.0'
```

Hope it will help!